# VB.net Objectlistview filtering column by range of numbers

Tags: vb.net, objectlistview

I have an objectlistview with a column of numbers ranging from -3000 to 10000.  I need to apply a filter for anything less than 2000 (this should include all the negative numbers as well).  I've read the examples and help (http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/filtering.html#filtering-label) but  it's in C# and I'm working with VB.net.  I can normally figure the conversion out but this one is stumping me.

I have another piece of code that uses a function instead of a delegate (when applying an image) but I couldn't get it to work in this filtering instance.  I also tried using a regex but I just feel that since I'm dealing with numbers I should do it without regex.

Can someone please show me a custom filtering example with number ranges in VB.net to help me get over this?

Thanks!

Here is an example I threw together:
[image]

When you click "Apply Filter", it should only show Mary Swanson and Jiminy Cricket (both under a height of 30).

Here is the code I used to create the olv

```
Private Sub Button3_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim LvLst As New List(Of Person)

    Dim LvItm As New Person With {.FirstName = "Joe",
                                  .LastName = "Blow",
                                  .Glasses = "Y",
                                  .Height = "75",
                                  .HeightBar = "75"}
    LvLst.Add(LvItm)

    Dim LvItm2 As New Person With {.FirstName = "Mary",
                                    .LastName = "Swanson",
                                    .Glasses = "N",
                                    .Height = "25",
                                    .HeightBar = "25"}
    LvLst.Add(LvItm2)

    Dim LvItm3 As New Person With {.FirstName = "Mike",
                                    .LastName = "Tyson",
                                    .Glasses = "N",
                                    .Height = "125",
                                    .HeightBar = "125"}

    LvLst.Add(LvItm3)

    Dim LvItm4 As New Person With {.FirstName = "Jiminy",
                                    .LastName = "Cricket",
                                    .Glasses = "Y",
                                    .Height = "-9",
                                    .HeightBar = "-9"}

    LvLst.Add(LvItm4)


    ObjectListView3.View = View.Details

    Dim myImages = New ImageList
    myImages.Images.Add(My.Resources.Hipster_Glasses_icon)
    myImages.Images.Add(My.Resources.Button_important_icon)
    ObjectListView3.SmallImageList = myImages

    ObjectListView3.UseCellFormatEvents = True
    ObjectListView3.OwnerDraw = True
    Col_Glasses.ImageGetter = Function(x As Object) As Integer
                                  Dim casted As Person = DirectCast(x, Person)
                                  If casted.Glasses = "Y" Then
                                      Return 0
                                  Else
                                      Return 1
                                  End If
                              End Function

    Col_Height.Renderer = New BarRenderer(0, 100, Pens.Black, Brushes.Gold)

    'Set no data message
    ObjectListView3.EmptyListMsg = "No Data Found"
    ObjectListView3.EmptyListMsgFont = New Font("Tahoma", 18)

    'Allows you to type and search inside the olv
    ObjectListView3.IsSearchOnSortColumn = True

    ObjectListView3.SetObjects(LvLst)

End Sub
```

And this is the code behind the filter button that I need help on

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ObjectListView3.ModelFilter = Function(x As Object) As ModelFilter

                                      Dim casted As Person = DirectCast(x, Person)

                                      If casted.Height <= CInt(HeightFilter.Text) Then
                                          Return x
                                      End If

                                  End Function
End Sub
```

Person Class

```
Public Class Person
  Public Property FirstName As String
  Public Property LastName As String
  Public Property Glasses As String
  Public Property Height As Integer
  Public Property HeightBar As Integer
End Class
```

The error says that IModelFilter is not a delegate type.  I don't know what i should be returning from the function??  Do you see the imagegetter I used for the glasses column?  I was trying to use the same approach but I've never used it for a IModelFilter.   Thanks for the help!

Comment: The example C# code looks pretty straightforward and should be easily translated to vb.net. Can you show what code you tried?

Comment: Convert c# to vb.net http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: hey @ChaseRocker I've updated the question as requested.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post the code for your `Person` class?

Comment: @chaserocker - Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the filter to a new ModelFilter. `x` is the object being passed into the function, cast it to your `Person`class, then filter by height. The filter basically returns True (to keep it) or False (to filter it out) as it processes each Person.

```
ObjectListView3.ModelFilter = New BrightIdeasSoftware.ModelFilter(Function(x) CType(x, Person).Height <= CInt(Me.HeightFilter.Text))
```

Comment: Thanks @ChaseRocker!  You saved me a ton of time.  For anyone else using this solution, the only other thing I had to change to make it work is to set UseFiltering to True (ObjectListView3.UseFiltering = True).